# The file name must end with .xml

Tags: android

I got error 'The file name must end with .xml' while installing apk on physical device there is one background img on that it showing this error
res/drawable/background.png
i tried bitmap to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use drawable folder to keep xml or vector drawables.
Use Mipmap, Raw or Assets folder to ship png images with the app.